# Improve English writing by oneself without human feedback?

Tags: writing

I was born in China and currently live and work in Hong Kong. English is my second language. My IELTS writing score (academic module) is in the 6 - 6.5 band range.

I have always wanted to write good English essays and other formats such as email, and therefore I tried to write about 200 - 400 words every day (diary, topics I find interesting, a summary of the news piece, forum post, etc.). However, I feel that my efforts are somewhat in vain when human feedback is absent. I can use computers (such as Microsoft Word or Grammarly) to correct my grammar and punctuation, but I do not know if my usage of wordings and style are proper. I do not want to bother my westerner friends too often, because I think they will be annoyed in a similar way as when I tried to correct their Chinese essays. The price for correcting an IELTS essay is about 15 USD for 250 words, which I find too expensive if I would like my daily exercise to be checked.

I tried reading the New York Times and non-fiction books (skim or intensive read). But I never like reading fiction (except Harry Potter). I think it improves my reading comprehension substantially, but not much in writing.

There is an old Chinese saying "You cannot write a good essay on the first time; you need to revise the essay repeatedly to achieve goodness" (I paraphrase a bit). So here is my question: **how should I revise my English essays by myself, or continuously improve my English writing, if I do not even know what good or bad writing is?** Actually, I have the same dilemma when writing in Chinese, but Chinese is not my concern at the moment.

I hope my question is not too vague to be answered. Further information can be provided if required.

Comment: I can relate to what you said. I am learning English as my third language. What about enrolling in courses where there are teachers to provide feedback? There are some online courses that don't cost an arm and a leg, and you can do it at your own time and pace.

Comment: @Jalene: thanks for your comment. I did join several online courses (both free and paid) and face-to-face courses before. My problem is that these courses aim at teaching you how to write rather than checking what you have written. Therefore, by asking "improve English writing", I am actually looking for alternative ways of "check my own work". It would be the best if there are self-sufficient ways.

Comment: Have you discovered this https://writing.stackexchange.com group yet? Maybe you can find some ideas from this thread https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/17615/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-publish-individual-chapters-of-my-book-idea-online-for-feedb/17715#17715

Comment: @Jalene No, I did not know the writing group. Thanks for the recommendation! I will check it out.

Comment: This was certainly off-topic on ELU, though I'm not sure it is on-topic here (my close-vote was a different one). You can't get round reading various sorts of literature to pick up good habits. I'd recommend Anne Perry; you might like EE Smith / Stephen Goldin ('Family d'Alembert'). _And almost all Anglophones have been / are being shown corrections by teachers at school._

Comment: You could look at something like: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang-8.com

Comment: You need to find a penpal where the other person is looking to correct their Chinese and they can correct your English. You then do an exchange.

Comment: @Jim Lang-8 seems a rather good option, however its new user registration is still in suspension.